# generate random objects and add to arraylist by percentage

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to randomly generate animals objects by percentage and then add them into an `ArrayList`.

In total, there should be 100 objects and it should be 40% of dogs, 25% of cats, 10% of cow, 20% lamb, 5% rabbit objects.

What I did was, I created a `for` loop, and add the objects. Is there a shortcut and make it simple that does the job without initializing all the `final int` variables?

What I did was this:

```java
final int ANIMAL_MAX = 100;
final int dog = 0;
final int cat = 0;
final int cow = 0;
final int lamb = 0;
final int rabbit = 0;
ArrayList <Animal> animal= new ArrayList <Animal>(ANIMAL_MAX);
for(int i=0;i<animal.size(); i++) {
    if(dog < (ANIMAL_MAX * 0.40)) {
        animal.add(new Dog(generateRandom()));
        dog++;
    }else if(cat < (ANIMAL_MAX * 0.25)) {
        animal.add(new Cat(generateRandom()));
        cat++;
    }else if(cow < (ANIMAL_MAX * 0.1)) {
        animal.add(new Cow(generateRandom()));
        cow++;
    }else if(lamb < (ANIMAL_MAX * 0.2)) {
        animal.add(new Lamb(generateRandom()));
        lamb++;
    }else if(rabbit < (ANIMAL_MAX * 0.05)) {
        animal.add(new Rabbit(generateRandom()));
        rabbit++;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have all the percentages, why not multiplying each percentage by 100 and generate that number of animals for each percentage of each animal?

Comment: @Daniel I'm already doing that, my question in this post is different.Is it possible to shrink this logic that i applied?

Comment: @JosephMartínez Your code has a logical error and it will generate 0 animal objects. First run your code, and check if it produces the required output. Then comes question of optimizing the logic, if at all needed.

Comment: `new ArrayList <Animal>(100);` only tells the expected size of the `ArrayList`, i.e. 100. And not the  actual size. Actual size is still 0. It only increases if you add something into the list. So your loop won't even start.

Answer (score 0):

Since the total number of animals is constant and the percentages for each animal are also constant, you can simply write a separate `for` loop for each animal and therefore no need for all the `final int` variables.

```java
final int ANIMAL_MAX = 100;
ArrayList<Animal> animal= new ArrayList<>(ANIMAL_MAX);
for (int i = ANIMAL_MAX * 0.4; --i >= 0;) {
    animal.add(new Dog(generateRandom()));
}
for (int i = ANIMAL_MAX * 0.25; --i >= 0;) {
    animal.add(new Cat(generateRandom()));
}
for (int i = ANIMAL_MAX * 0.1; --i >= 0;) {
    animal.add(new Cow(generateRandom()));
}
for (int i = ANIMAL_MAX * 0.2; --i >= 0;) {
    animal.add(new Lamb(generateRandom()));
}
for (int i = ANIMAL_MAX * 0.05; --i >= 0;) {
    animal.add(new Rabbit(generateRandom()));
}
```

Comment: Nice job looping from `MAX` to `0`, and merging the loop condition and decrement into single statement. Keep it simple while answering the beginners.